# XGBoost hyper tuned parameters give a lower accuracy compared to the default model

Tags: machine-learning, xgboost, hyperparameters, mlr

Problem: XGBoost hyper tuned parameters give a lower accuracy compared to the default model.

I have a question regarding the XGBoost algorithm. The goal is to predict a multiclass classification variable. The dataframe consists of 2600 observations with 55 features. Im working in R and therefore performing hyperparameter tuning with the MLR package. The test and train data set are stratified with 20-80% division. The data is a bit imbalanced.

test_y:
0   1   2   3
278  64  37 155

train_y
0    1    2    3
1126  216  159  637

As stated above, the problem is that the accuracy of the default model is higher (for both the test and training dataset), which is very weird. The code is below. Does anyone know where I am making a mistake? Or what can I check or improve?

The loss function of the xgboost function is mlogloss but the evaluation metric is 'acc'. Is that a problem?

Also, I read about different hyperparameter optimization methods (Bayesian, random search, gridsearch (hyperopt, mlrmbo, ...). Could it help to try others?

```
### default
traintask <- makeClassifTask(data = df_train, 
                             target = "more_than_X_perc_damage")
testtask <- makeClassifTask(data = df_test, 
                            target = "more_than_X_perc_damage")

xgb_params_def <- list(booster = "gbtree", 
               objective = "multi:softprob", 
               eta=0.3, 
               gamma=0, 
               max_depth=6, 
               min_child_weight=1, 
               subsample=1, 
               colsample_bytree=1,
               alpha = 0,
               lambda = 1, 
               nrounds = 100)

lrn <- makeLearner("classif.xgboost",
                   predict.type = "prob", 
                   par.vals = list(objective="multi:softprob",
                                   eval_metric="mlogloss"))

xgb_def <- setHyperPars(learner = lrn,
                        par.vals = xgb_params_def)

xgb_model_def <- mlr::train(xgb_def, traintask)

# prediction performance
pred <- predict(xgb_model_def, testtask)
stats_def <- confusionMatrix(pred$data$response,pred$data$truth)
stats_def$overall[1] # accuracy
```

```
### tuned pars
# set resampling strategy (cross-validation)
rdesc <- makeResampleDesc("CV",stratify = T,iters=10L) 
# set random search in param set
ctrl <- makeTuneControlRandom(maxit = 1000L) 

lrn <- makeLearner("classif.xgboost",
                   predict.type = "prob",
                   par.vals = list(objective="multi:softprob", 
                                   eval_metric="mlogloss"))

params_to_tune <- makeParamSet(makeIntegerParam("max_depth",lower =3L,upper = 10L),
                               makeNumericParam("min_child_weight",lower = 0L,upper = 5L),
                               makeNumericParam("subsample",lower = 0.5,upper = 1),
                               makeNumericParam("eta", lower = 0.03, upper = 0.3),
                               makeNumericParam("colsample_bytree",lower = 0.5,upper = 1),
                               makeNumericParam("gamma",lower = 0,upper = 100),
                               makeNumericParam("alpha",lower = -1, upper = 0, trafo = function(x) 10^x),
                               makeNumericParam("lambda", lower = -1, upper = 0, trafo = function(x) 10^x), 
                               makeIntegerParam("nrounds", lower = 30L, upper = 500L))

tuned_params <- tuneParams(learner = lrn,
                           task = traintask, 
                           resampling = rdesc,
                           measures = acc, 
                           par.set = params_to_tune, 
                           control = ctrl,
                           show.info = T)

xgb_tuned_learner <- setHyperPars(learner = lrn,
                                  par.vals = tuned_params$x)

xgb_model <- mlr::train(xgb_tuned_learner, traintask)

# prediction performance
pred <- predict(xgb_model, testtask)
stats <- confusionMatrix(pred$data$response,pred$data$truth)
stats $overall[1] # accuracy
```

Comment: Not entirely sure what you're asking -- you say that the accuracy of the default model is both lower and higher than the tuned model. I'm assuming that you mean what you say in the title. Your code snippets are missing the data, so I can't reproduce what you're doing. There's also a lot of other stuff going on -- can you reduce it to a minimal example please? Finally, it looks like you're training the default and tuned models differently.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff Thank you for your response! Indeed, I meant that the default model is performing better. I have reduced it to a minimal example. Unfortunately, I can not share the data. I would appreciate it if you could have a look again!

Comment: Could be that your train and test sets are very different, e.g. balanced differently between the classes.

Comment: Thank you for your response Lars! I will have a look.